# Adding a list to an empty python list issue

Tags: python, list, loops, append, range

I am Python beginner with no prior programming experience.
I apologize in advance if this question sounds too lame to answer to, but there is something I am confused with. It's related to adding a particular list (l2) to an empty list (l1).
What I am trying to do is to increase the value of each of the "l2" elements in each iteration, and then add it to the l2 list.Here is the code:

```
l1 = []
l2 = [0,1,2,3]

for i in range(3):
    l2[0] = l2[0] + 1
    l2[1] = l2[1] + 1
    l2[2] = l2[2] + 1
    l2[3] = l2[3] + 1
    print l2
    l1.append(l2)

print l1
```

This is the print result that I get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[[3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Why doesn't l2 list look like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

?
Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 5):

It is because you are appending the same list object each time. You need to copy the list object before you append it, so that you are sure you append a different object.

```
l1.append(l2[:])
```

Answer (score 4):

That is because when you append `l2` to `l1`, you are actually keeping the reference to the same list. Therefore, when you modify `l2`, the instance is the same as that which was appended to `l1` and therefore that gets modified as well. You should do it as follows:

```
for i in range(3):
    l2[0] = l2[0] + 1
    l2[1] = l2[1] + 1
    l2[2] = l2[2] + 1
    l2[3] = l2[3] + 1
    print l2
    l1.append(l2[:])

>>> print l1
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

#### Explanation

Here, the `[:]` is called list splicing. It follows the following format: `[a:b]` where `a` is the start index of a list and the `b` is the end index of the string (excluded). Without specifying any arguments, the `[:]` essentially creates a copy of the list and appends the **copy**.

#### Examples

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> print a[2]
c

>>> print a[:]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

>>> print a[2:4]
['c', 'd']

>>> print a[:3]
['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> print a[1:]
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: Thank you for an instant reply sshashank. But I am not sure I understand. Why does the "print l2" show the correct 'result' then?
Is there a difference between the "l2" from "print l2" and "l2" from "l1.append(l2)"?

Comment: @user3137724, Because you are doing `print l2` straight away. Whereas,  you keep appending the values while also altering the previous values and the print it at the end.

Comment: @user3137724, You are in a sense appending the same object you are then later changing. What you want to do is create a copy of the object so far and then append __that__ so that when you make future changes to the original `l2` the copy that exists in your `l1` does __not__ get affected. It does take a while to wrap one's head around. Hope that was clear. Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Because you're adding the list l2 itself, and not a copy of it. That's why, at the end of the loop when you print it, you get a list with the last l2 values.

You can use this trick below to create a copy of l2 and then add it to l1:

```
l1.append(l2[:])
```